# Gmail Api / GmailApp Apps Script Is there any way to tag a message when someone is replying to it?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api

We have a shared inbox between several people using the same account, and sometimes we answer the same messages 2/3 times, we solved this manually marking the mails that are going to be answered but it would be nice to have something that is automatic.

I thought about monitoring the last 10 drafts that are generated, tagging the mails that have the same subject using the draft internal date:

```
var draftDate = Gmail.Users.Drafts.get('me','r-3713120909044645691').message.internalDate
```

Deleting them and unchecking them from the monitoring queue once they are sent. But I can't think of any other way.

Comment: When you say `to tag a message`, do you mean to [label](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/118708) them? Also, could you provide more details about which messages you want to label, when, which label, etc.?

Comment: I mean to star, but tagging is a possibility. I want to flag/label/star a message when someone from my team opens it to respond.

Comment: In order to label the message when users are replying to it, you could use a Gmail add-on with a [compose trigger](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/gmail/extending-compose-ui). I don't think there's an analogous trigger for when the message is sent, so I'm not sure it is worth having an add-on. Therefore, I think tracking the internal dates with a [time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) might be the best option. Did you try doing that? What problems (if any) did you face?

Comment: I have to study compose triggers. I have found a solution, but the problem now is having to refresh the page manually to see the tagging changes to mails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a getLastMails() function that searches through the tags of the last message from the last 10 Mailthreads, if it finds any drafts it tags them as "REPLYING", if it finds mails tagged as "REPLYING" and they are not drafts, it removes the label.
The problem I am having now is that I have to refresh the mails every time before replying to see the if there is any changes on the tagged mails.

What I don't know is how efficient it is in terms of quota limits.

```js
function getLastMails() {

var mails = Gmail.Users.Messages.list('me')['messages'].forEach((message, i) => {

if (i<10) {


var messageObj = Gmail.Users.Messages.get('me', message.id)
var messageId = message.id

var labels = messageObj.labelIds


if(labels.includes("DRAFT")){
  var gappMessage =GmailApp.getMessageById(messageId)
  GmailApp.starMessage(gappMessage)
  editLabel(message.id, "REPLYING")
  //GmailApp.refreshThreads
}

if(labels.includes(getLabelByName("REPLYING",'id'))&&!labels.includes("DRAFT")) {
  var gappMessage =GmailApp.getMessageById(messageId)
  GmailApp.unstarMessage(gappMessage)
  editLabel(message.id,'',"REPLYING")
  //GmailApp.refreshThreads
}



}

})

}



function getLabel(label_){
var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(label_);
return label || GmailApp.createLabel(label_);

}


function getLabelByName(name,field){
  var label_ = getLabel(name);

  return Gmail.Users.Labels.list('me')['labels'].filter( lab => lab.name == name )[0][field]
}

function editLabel(idMail, labelAdd = "", labelRemove = "" ) {

labelRemove = (labelRemove == "") ? [] : [getLabelByName(labelRemove,'id')];
labelAdd = (labelAdd == "") ? []: [getLabelByName(labelAdd,'id')];


Gmail.Users.Messages.modify({
   "addLabelIds": labelAdd ,
   "removeLabelIds": labelRemove
 }, 'me',idMail);




}
```

Comment: When is this supposed to run? I thought part of the issue was executing this at the right time (when the user starts composing the reply). I guess a time-driven trigger could be appropriate though.